# unfortunately app_name (DateWithMe) has stopped

Tags: android

I am getting problem when i run my project as unfortunately app has stopped. i have posted my code. I wanna connect my app with sq-lite database. can u provide me with the working model . i simply store and retrieve values during execution.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#999999" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:onClick="login_sigin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/log_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:onClick="login_sigin"
                android:text="Log In" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:text=" Welcome "
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#999999" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >



                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_hide2"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Mobile No."
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:inputType="phone" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signin2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Sign in" 
            android:onClick="action"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="action"
            android:text="Continue.." />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:background="#999999"
            >
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email id"
            android:maxLength="40"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/email_id"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:hint="Mobile No."
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName">
            <requestFocus />
          </EditText>  

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email_id"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email_id"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email_id"
            android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >



                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_hide"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Log in" 
            android:onClick="action"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Continue.."
            android:onClick="action"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#999999">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/w_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/w_welcome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/w_image"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w_image"
            android:text="Welcome Mohsin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#444444"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and my Login.java

```
 package com.example.datewithme;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Login extends Activity{
        Intent i=null;
        ImageView im=null;
        EditText tv1,tv4;
        boolean flag=false;
        SQLiteDatabase db=null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show_hide2);
            tv1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone2);
            tv4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password2);
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        //  db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,mobile_no varchar,email_id varchar,password varchar,flag varchar)");

            im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    if(flag==false)
                    {

                        tv4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        flag=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        tv4.setInputType(129);
                        flag=false;

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void action(View v)
        {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.signin2: 
            i=new Intent(this,Signin.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 500);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom); 
            finish();
            break;
         case R.id.start:
            String mobile_no=tv1.getText().toString();
            String password=tv4.getText().toString();
            if(mobile_no==null||mobile_no==""||mobile_no.length()<10)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
            }
            else if(password==null||password==""||password.length()<6)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct Password.");
            }
            else
            {       
                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from login where mobile_no='"+mobile_no+"' and password='"+password+"'",null);   
                c.moveToFirst();
                if(c.getCount()>0)
                {
                i=new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,500);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left); 
                db.close();
                finish();
                }
                else
                    show("Wrong Password or Mobile number.");

            }
            break;
        }
      }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        } 

        public void show(String str)
        {
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }

    }
```

and my MainActivity

```
 package com.example.datewithme;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

and my Signin .java

```
package com.example.datewithme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Signin extends Activity{
    Intent i=null;
    ImageView im=null;
    EditText tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
    boolean flag=false;
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin);
        im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show_hide);
        tv1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_id);
        tv3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        tv4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,mobile_no varchar,email_id varchar,password varchar,flag varchar)");

        im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(flag==false)
                {

                    tv4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    flag=true;
                }
                else
                {

                    tv4.setInputType(129);
                    flag=false;

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void action(View v)
    {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.login: 
        i=new Intent(this,Login.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 500);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom); 
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.signin:
        String name=tv1.getText().toString();
        String email_id=tv2.getText().toString();
        String mobile_no=tv3.getText().toString();
        String password=tv4.getText().toString();
        if(name==null||name==""||name.length()<3)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Name.");
        }
        else if(mobile_no==null||mobile_no==""||mobile_no.length()<10)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
        }
        else if(email_id==null||email_id==""||email_id.length()<10)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Email id.");
        }
        else if(password==null||password==""||password.length()<6)
        {
            show("Please Enter Strong Password.");
        }
        else
        {
            db.execSQL("insert into login values('"+name+"','"+mobile_no+"','"+email_id+"','"+password+"','nothing')");
            i=new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 500);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left); 
            db.close();
            finish();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    } 

    public void show(String str)
    {
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
}
```

and welcome.java

```
package com.example.datewithme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Welcome extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    }
}
```

// logcat errors

```
  02-14 00:50:12.357: D/gralloc_goldfish(1045): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    02-14 00:50:32.427: D/AndroidRuntime(1045): Shutting down VM
    02-14 00:50:32.427: W/dalvikvm(1045): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4af8b90)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Process: com.example.datewithme, PID: 1045
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method login_sigin(View) in the activity class com.example.datewithme.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'sign_in'
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3801)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: login_sigin [class android.view.View]
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3794)
    02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     ... 11 more
    02-14 00:50:37.817: I/Process(1045): Sending signal. PID: 1045 SIG: 9
    02-14 00:50:41.567: D/gralloc_goldfish(1071): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    02-14 00:50:46.827: D/AndroidRuntime(1071): Shutting down VM
    02-14 00:50:46.827: W/dalvikvm(1071): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4af8b90)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071): Process: com.example.datewithme, PID: 1071
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method login_sigin(View) in the activity class com.example.datewithme.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'log_in'
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3801)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: login_sigin [class android.view.View]
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3794)
    02-14 00:50:46.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1071):     ... 11 more
    02-14 00:55:13.447: D/gralloc_goldfish(1098): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    02-14 00:55:17.007: D/AndroidRuntime(1098): Shutting down VM
    02-14 00:55:17.007: W/dalvikvm(1098): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4af8b90)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): Process: com.example.datewithme, PID: 1098
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method login_sigin(View) in the activity class com.example.datewithme.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'sign_in'
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3801)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: login_sigin [class android.view.View]
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3794)
    02-14 00:55:17.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     ... 11 more
    02-14 00:56:38.717: I/Process(1098): Sending signal. PID: 1098 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Give us the code and logcat for error.

Comment: Message is pretty clear!

Comment: Please try below solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `android:onClick="login_sigin"` and `android:onClick="login_sigin"` this from your button in XML

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="login_sigin"
            android:text="Sign In"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="login_sigin"/>
```

Because you have defined onClick event for this and you are not using it. So your button in XML should like this.

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Sign In" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/log_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Log In" />
```

In error it self it clearly defined that

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method login_sigin(View) in the activity class com.example.datewithme.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'sign_in'
```

Comment: i have made changes as u told..even then its showing unfortunately DateWithMe has stopped.

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting, because i don't think you are getting same error.

Comment: How it is possible that you got an error message and you didn't get log, definitely you are getting log, check twice still if you are not getting log then restart your eclipse and try to run it you will get log error message.

Answer (score 1):

**LogCat Output :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method login_sigin(View) in the activity class com.example.datewithme.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'sign_in'
02-14 00:50:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: login_sigin [class android.view.View]
```

*Logcat itself gives you the hint of your mistake as well as solution. try to read and understand.*

As you had declared `onClick` method for `sign_in` and `log_in` buttons in your `login.xml` file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Sign In"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/log_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="login_sigin"/>
```

**`You must add method to your java file with a name given in onClick attribute.`**

In your code you forgot to write `login_sigin()` method in your `login.java` file

add this method to your `login.java`

```
public void login_sigin(view v) {

 // Actions

}
```